# Ввод с кливиатуры и exeption

Tags: java, scanner, try-catch

Привет всем! Пишу консольное приложение. В  **switch**  я поставил ввод с клавиатуры,но если юзер введет не число - летит exeption и программа закрывается. как сделать что-бы "на лету" проверялся тип данных?Я пробывал в catch рукурсию засунуть.Не работает:))

```
@Override
public int startMenu() { //переделать в свитч // закинуть на стакоф
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.println("Добрый день! \nСделайте выбор:\n1)Cоздать список.\n2)Выход");
    int choice = 0;
    int result = 0;
    try {
        while (true) {
            choice = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

            switch (choice){
                case 1 : result = 1;
                break;
                case 2 : result = 2;
                break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Ошибка выбора операции.Сделайте выбор и введите номер операции!");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Ошибка выбора операции.Сделайте выбор и введите номер операции!");

    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Сделайте через `if(reader.readLine().getClass() != Integer.class) break; `, прежде, чем парсить число.

Comment: Сейчас попробую.Волнует такой момент: если юзер вводит кучу раз String ,вместо Integer-а -возможно ли этот процесс зациклить,что-б выводило -"введите целое число" . Возможно вашим вариантом оно проверит вводимое,но юзер может вводить и вводить далее символы.
П,С, не знаю, понятен ли ход моих мыслей:)

Comment: Если проверка не пройдет цикл завершится. И пользователя выбросит за неправильный ввод, если хотите продолжать цикл, используйте команду `continue`, для продолжения, а перед ней выбивайте сообщение, о том, что он  ввел не число.

Comment: if(reader.readLine().getClass() != Integer.class){
                    break;
                }
подчеркивает красным. Operator cannot be applied...

Comment: Упс. Сразу не подумал, что там не совместимость. Вам нужно проверить. число это или нет, все, что требуется. Или вообще просто проверить на `NumberFormatException` и делать `return false;` если ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public int startMenu() {        
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.println("Добрый день! \nСделайте выбор:\n1)Cоздать список.\n2)Выход");
    int choice = 0;
    int result = 0;
    boolean bool = false;
    while (!bool) {
        try {
            choice = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

            switch (choice) {
            case 1 : 
                result = 1;
                bool = true;
                break;
            case 2 :
                result = 2;
                bool = true;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Ошибка выбора операции. Сделайте выбор и введите номер операции!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Ошибка выбора операции. Введите целое число!");
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: так тут то же самое что и я написал. тут в строке : choice = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine()); вылетает ексепшн при вводе символа и программа "падает"

Comment: не падает, т.к. всё это в цикле while

Comment: @АлександрБезбородов для чего используется `result`? Добавьте фрагмент кода, в котором используется это возвращаемое значение

Comment: падает! Обрабатывается блоком catch  и все. Попробуйте сами.

Comment: @АлександрБезбородов исключение обработано, ничего не падает, я проверял. После `default` или `catch` цикл `while` продожает выполнение и можно снова вводить данные.

Comment: вставил все в цикл,работает.Спасибо:)

Answer (score 0):

```
public int startMenu() { //переделать в свитч // закинуть на стакоф
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Добрый день! \nСделайте выбор:\n1)Cоздать список.\n2)Выход");
    while (true) {
        try {
            int result = Integer.valueOf(reader.readLine());
            if (result == 1 || result == 2) return result;
            else throw new IOException();
        } catch (IOException | NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.out.println("Ошибка выбора операции.Сделайте выбор и введите номер операции!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: пробуйте так, тут ничего не упадет , метод будет выполняться до корректного воода

Comment: Если хотите, то можете заменить if на switch , просто я не вижу смысла в блоке switch , если есть всего 2 варианта...

Comment: зачем выбрасывать исключение и сразу же ловить. Какой-то goto в свои не лучшие годы получился. Тут лучше разделить логику на выбор неверного пункта и ввод текста вместо цифр.

Comment: блок else подразумевает, что пользователь ввел цифры, но это не 1 и не 2, т.е. ввод тоже некорретный. посему можете в блоке else написать System.out.println("Ошибка выбора операции.Сделайте выбор и введите номер операции!"), фактически дублируя одну и ту же строчку кода, а можете выбросить исключение и пользоваться указанной строчкой во всех случаях некорректного ввода. Вы просили избавиться от падения программы - я показал как это сделать. Дальше корректируйте код как вам угодно. можете поставить switch, можете поменять код в блоке else. Это не имеет большого значения

Comment: спасибо за совет!Хорошего вечера)

Comment: не за что, рад, что у вас получилось)